# I'm getting a new computer, how can I export my eclipse keystore? Please help?

Tags: android, eclipse, migration, export, keystore

In Eclipse, I have signed my Android apps by exporting the project and signing it with a key in the keystore. I don't know where those keys are being stored, but I just type in the name of the store, and it's there.

I'm getting ready to get a new computer, and I need to make sure that I can sign my Android apps on my new computer! How can I retain the saem keystore access? I have been trying different things with no luck...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in your project directory of your workspace - you should see a file called `release.keystore`. I'm guessing that might have something to do with it.

In short, just zip your entire workspace, and unzip it onto your new computer with the same directory structure. Then try things out and check you're able to access the keystore and export your project(s).

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, and someone correct me if I am, but your keystore should be located in a sub-directory of your Eclipse working directory. That is where mine is located. Check there first. If that doesn't prove useful, do a system search for any .keystore files and should that not help you may have to create a new keystore and key.